# VB.NET Drawing Text Above Controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, components

This is a really simple issue that I am having, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work. I've looked a round but haven't been able to get any similar solutions to work properly.

Basically, I have two panels on a simple form, A & B, with B being nested inside of A.

*Note, Panel A has a background Image, and both panels colors are set to transparen*t

I want to draw a string inside of Panel B, and it needs to be visible, so it draws above panel A.

I've tried overriding the Paint method of panel B, but that does not work. When using the code  below, the text draws to the screen when Panel B is not nested inside of panel A (such as next to panel A)

```
Private Sub panelB_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles panelB.Paint

        e.Graphics.DrawString("My Text", New Font("Arial", 60, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Orange, New Point(0, 0))
        panelB.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with drawing on the `panel`, however you cannot call `Refresh` in the paint event - it's like an infinite loop and will draw nothing. Refresh fires the paint event.

Comment: That only stops the flickering, which is useful. However, it doesn't affect my main problem.

Comment: Ok, I don't get the problem here. I can draw text on a transparent panel. Realize in Winforms you don't have true transparency if multiple panels are overlapping.

Comment: I don't really know how else to explain it. I have two panels, with Panel B being on top of Panel A, the text from the paint method of panelB is not visible

Comment: Like I said above, it's not true transparency. Move to WPF to get that kind of control.